# use of md5 for protecting file integrity over http/https call

Tags: md5, checksum

A common way to ensure integrity of a file uploaded from a client is to include the md5 header in the request which can be used by the server for the same.

I would like to know that if a file can be corrupted on its way, then why can't a header be corrupted thus causing the server verification to be useless.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify the tech? (http?) ed: scratch that, i see your title includes "rest call"

Comment: Nowadays, with TLS being so simple to deploy, it's common to let TLS handle integrity verification, which it does very well (in addition to providing secrecy and authentication).  You might be thinking of integrity verification of a file transfer over an unencrypted connection.  In this case, sending the checksum along with the file will protect against unintentional transmission errors in the network, but will not protect against an active attacker for the reason that you mention in your question.